# Codeigniter: load library array with default parameter array and other library in one line code

Tags: php, codeigniter, constructor

Hi Below is the current code sample:

As it can be seen, i have to load the library `mylog` separately with default parameter array.

```
$this->load->library(['tank_auth', 'session', 'form_validation']);
$log_config = array(
    'module' => 'estate',
);
$this->load->library('mylog', $log_config);
```

Is there any way to load the `mylog` library with others in one line as it has the default parameters `$log_config` array to be passed with it?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Negative voting without any comments or even have guts to answer this..Funny? 
Hey voters: at-least respect that this answer has some meaning. because although it is not solvable it serves purpose for other users not to search more.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to load your library with others in one line as it has the default parameters as array to be passed with it.

You cannot load library array with default parameter array and other library in one line code.

As per the Codeigniter docs, you can load library like in your question

```
$this->load->library(['tank_auth', 'session', 'form_validation']);
```

or

"library" with a single argument: an array of parameters,  as in your question:

```
$log_config = array(
    'module' => 'estate',
);
$this->load->library('mylog', $log_config);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can't understand the mindset of negative voters. is it something like 'The unsolvable' can't be questioned here? but how do we know it's not-solvable without asking? :P